# SQL (maybe basic) - QUERY with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

- Student (name, studentNumber) - student table
- Enrollments (enrollmentNumber, studentNumber, subject) - table with subjects in which the student has enrolled
- Grades (studentNumber, subject, grade) - table with the test grades

I've this task:

> Write a SQL instruction that returns the name of the student, the enrolled subject and the grades the student
>   obtained in the subject. The SQL instruction should also return the students that enrolled in a 
>   subject and did not attend the tests of that subject (in this case, the student will be present 
>   in the Enrollments table but not in the Grades table).

I developed this query:

```
SELECT * FROM student s
    LEFT JOIN enrollments e ON s.studentNumber = e.studentNumber
    LEFT JOIN grades g ON e.studentNumber = g.studentNumber
    WHERE e.subject = g.subject
```

I know the error is in the last WHERE, because the enrollments with no grades don't show up (which makes sense)... Can anyone help-me figuring this one out?

Comment: Try change the second LEFT JOIN to the student table instead

Comment: The query is working, but not as intended, I really wanted that enrollments rows get in the output when there is no grade to that enrollment+studentNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move 
            "e.subject = g.subject" 
as a filter on the left join.  when you use a filter on an outer join as part of the where, it effectively turns it into an INNER JOIN:

```
    SELECT * FROM student s
      LEFT JOIN enrollments e ON s.studentNumber = e.studentNumber
      LEFT JOIN grades g ON e.studentNumber = g.studentNumber
          AND e.subject = g.subject
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked so perfectly! I don't belive I was so close! :D